# Difference between Platform and Target Platform in windows Application

Tags: c#, windows-installer, platform

I am creating  MSI file in Windows 7(x64).

I have doubt on Platform.Let me know Difference between Platform and Target Platform

Select MSI Project->Press F4 (property window will come)

[image: property window]

Select MSI Project->Right Click->Properties->Configuration Manager

[image: Configuration Manager]

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1hy4dhz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

**Platform**

Displays the platform on which the desired build must run and lists all of the available platforms for the project. To add a new platform or edit an existing one, choose  or  from this drop-down list. The kind of project you are working with determines whether you can add more than one platform and what platforms are available for you to add to the project. When you add a platform for a project, a new project configuration is created.

**Target Platform**

It is the platform for which you want your project to run.Let's say if you have 32 bit application changing the Target platform to x64 will allow it to run on 64 Bit machines as well your target here is 64 Bit Machines.

Comment: Let me confirm that that , if any application is created in windows 7(x64), is this  called as 64 bit application ? if yes, is it possible if i keep target plartform : x86 , is this msi file will work on 32 bit system.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what if 64 bit Process

Comment: @Havab If you have 32-bit hardware, you cannot run a 64-bit